# Superhero words!

Tags: word, wordplay, no-computers, graph-theory

Quietly walking among us are words which are actually superheroes in disguise!  Just as Diana Prince spins around to become Wonder Woman, some seemingly ordinary words can spin around to reveal their super identities!

For example, STRESSED turns into DESSERTS just when you need it, and REVILED can turn around to DELIVER.

Meanwhile...
Poor little THINK is sitting all alone, thinking about how he could become the KNIGHT, if only he had a spare "G" ...

Just a mere mortal word without powers of transformation?  Well, never fear!  There is no shame in using an accessory (or ten) to enable your superpowers!  (Respect, Batman, Green Lantern, and Iron Man!)

So now STINGIER can become the fiery REIGNITES(1), EMERGED can become the brilliant doctor DEGREE(2), and SALAMI can become fleet-footed IMPALAS(3)!
(1) with addition of an "E", sold separately
(2) after subtraction of an "M", not responsible for lost or missing pieces
(3) with addition of a "P", not included

But wait, there's more!  With a well-stocked utility belt, some words can take on multiple transformations!

For example, DUAL becomes DUEL through the following transformation sequence:

```
 DUAL
.   .
 . .
  .         ---U-->
 . .
.   .
 LAD
.   .
 . .
  .         <--E---
 . .
.   .
 DEAL
.   .
 . .
  .         ---A-->
 . .
.   .
 LED
.   .
 . .
  .         <--U---
 . .
.   .
 DUEL
```

Now let's see if you can help other superhero words find their own transformation sequence!

At each step, you may add or subtract a letter as you choose.  You don't need to alternate additions and subtractions.

As always, I construct my puzzles in such a way that they can be solved using only well-known words, so if you find yourself conjuring up increasingly obscure words, you may be overthinking it.

The first three are just to get you warmed up, while 4-8 are serious:

```
1.  start:  SCAM
    end:    MAGES
    (suggested 2 intermediate words)


2.  start:  TROOPER
    end:    TROOPED
    (suggested 3 intermediate words)


3.  start:  XENON
    end:    WOK
    (suggested 5 intermediate words)


4.  start:  SLEEPY
    end:    SLEEPER
    (suggested 16 intermediate words)


5.  start:  SEAPORT
    end:    SPIRITS
    (suggested 17 intermediate words)


6.  start:  KNIGHT
    end:    TIME
    (suggested 23 intermediate words)


7.  start:  GURU
    end:    SERIES
    (suggested 27 intermediate words)


8.  start:  BLOG
    end:    ABOUT
    (suggested 36 intermediate words)
```

Super helpful hints or diabolical distractions?
[guar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Guar) vs. [gaur](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaur)
[taro](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Colocasia_esculenta) vs. [tarot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tarot)

---

Epilogue:

Wow, we really got a refresher on some vocabulary-building words!  GARS, DIT, DEMIT, SOU, SOT, SI, STIM, STOB, NOB, TA, TAT...

1-3 were nicely handled by @Mohirl

Note on 4:

> The solution provided by @PiIsNot3 is well done.  If you feel that LEE is no longer as well known as it once was, take a look at the solution provided by @arbitrahj which detours around it using
>
>   SEE --> EVES --> SEVER --> REVELS --> LEVER --> REEL

Alternative solution to 5:

> SEAPORT --> TROPES --> SPORT --> TOPS --> POT --> TO --> OAT --> TARO --> RAT --> TARS --> SAT --> TEAS --> SET --> TIES --> SIT --> TIPS --> SPITS --> STRIPS --> SPIRITS

Alternative solution to 6:

> KNIGHT --> THINK --> KNIT --> STINK --> NITS --> SIN --> IS --> SIT --> TIES --> SET --> TEAS --> SAT --> TARS --> RAT --> TARO --> OAT --> TO --> LOT --> TOIL --> LIT --> TILE --> RELIT --> TIER --> REMIT --> TIME

Note on 7:

> The solution provided by @PiIsNot3 uses GARS.  Here is an alternative to the segment from RAG to PAR:
>
>   RAG --> GARB --> BAG --> GRAB --> BAR --> CRAB --> ARC --> CRAP --> PAR

Alternative solution to 8:

> BLOG --> GOB --> BOGS --> SOB --> BOBS --> BOB --> BOMB --> MOB --> BOOM --> MOO --> DOOM --> MOD --> DORM --> ROD --> DOER --> RED --> DEAR --> RAD --> DART --> TAD --> AT --> A --> AD --> DAB --> BAUD --> DUB --> BUDS --> SUB --> US --> SUN --> NUBS --> BUN --> SNUB --> BUS --> STUB --> BUT --> TUBA --> ABOUT

Comment: With the suggested number of intermediate steps, do you really mean the number of intermediate words? I think of a step as the process of going from one word to the next, in which case there would be one more intermediate steps than intermediate words.

Comment: @JaapScherphuis — Ah, good call!  I changed it to clarify that I meant intermediate *words*, not counting the start and end word.  It's the old, tricky question of how many treads versus how many risers in a staircase.

Comment: Just to confirm - We must add/subtract a letter each time, so can't use a "superhero" word along the way, right?

Comment: @JaapScherphuis — At each intermediate step, you must reverse the previous word and either add or subtract a letter.  The result must be a word, any word, as long as it's a word.  It might even be a reversible or palindromatic word in itself, but that won't help you for the next step because you will have to add or remove a letter anyway.

Comment: *  It's the old, tricky question of how many steps (treads versus risers) in a staircase?  Tread count gives N, while riser count gives N+1.

Comment: haha! I love all of your word puzzles! I think they're really witty.

Comment: is `(2) after subtraction of a "G", not responsible for lost or missing pieces` supposed to be `(2) after subtraction of a "M", not responsible for lost or missing pieces`

Comment: Now i've learned to use DEMIT instead of DAMMIT ;) XD Nice puzzle, btw, take my upvote! (upvoted alr)

Comment: @SlowMagic thanks for the tick mark! This was a really fun challenge :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Partial**

SLEEPY -> SLEEPER (14 words):

> (Based off of arbitrahj’s answer) 
>  SLEEPY 
>  PEELS 
>  SEEP 
>  PEE 
>  WEEP 
>  PEW 
>  WE 
>  EWE 
>  EWES 
>  SEE 
>  EELS 
>  LEE 
>  REEL 
>  LEPER 
>  REPELS 
>  SLEEPER

SEAPORT -> SPIRITS (11 words):

> SEAPORT 
>  TROPES 
>  SPORT 
>  TOPS 
>  SOT (not sure if this is considered a “common” word or not) 
>  TOES 
>  SET 
>  TIES 
>  SIT 
>  TIPS 
>  SPITS 
>  STRIPS 
>  SPIRITS

KNIGHT -> TIME (11 words):

> KNIGHT 
>  THINK 
>  KNIT 
>  TIN 
>  IT 
>  TIP 
>  PI 
>  DIP 
>  ID 
>  DIT 
>  TIED 
>  DEMIT 
>  TIME

GURU -> SERIES (25 words)

> GURU 
>  RUG 
>  GUAR 
>  RAG 
>  GARS 
>  SAG 
>  GAPS 
>  SPA 
>  RAPS 
>  PAR 
>  RAPT 
>  TAR 
>  AT 
>  TAD 
>  DART 
>  RAD 
>  DEAR 
>  RED 
>  DEER 
>  REEDS 
>  SEER 
>  FREES 
>  SERF 
>  FIRES 
>  SERIFS 
>  SIRES 
>  SERIES

BLOG -> ABOUT (20 words):

> BLOG 
>  GOB (?) 
>  BONG 
>  NOB (?) 
>  BORN 
>  ROB 
>  OR 
>  ROD 
>  DO 
>  SOD 
>  DUOS 
>  SOU (?) 
>  US 
>  SUN 
>  NUBS 
>  BUN 
>  SNUB 
>  BUS 
>  STUB 
>  BUT 
>  TUBA 
>  ABOUT

Comment: Yep, the SEAPORT one looks fine to me. Nice one!

Answer (score 9):

Well, I'll start by taking the two easy ones:

SCAM -> MAGES:

> SCAM -> MACES -> SEAM -> MAGES

TROOPER -> TROOPED

> TROOPER -> REPORT -> TROPE -> DEPORT -> TROOPED

XENON -> WOK

> XENON -> NONE -> EON -> NO -> WON -> KNOW -> WOK

SEAPORT -> SPIRITS (25, sure I've gone the long way around) (23 now, 2 thanks to @Jaap Scherphuis )

> SEAPORT -> TROPES -> SPORT -> TOPS  -> POT -> TO -> OAT -> TA -> TAT -> AT -> TAP -> PANT ->  NAP -> PAIN -> NIP -> PINS -> SIP -> IS -> SIT -> TIPS -> SPITS -> STRIPS -> SPIRITS

Comment: You can go straight from TOPS to POT, shortening it by two.

Comment: Good work on SEAPORT!
If "TA" is bothering you, consider my diabolical hints.  Or not.

Comment: Ah!! Thanks Jaap. I started from both ends and worked towards the middle, obviously went too far on one side!

Comment: You can’t go from OAT to TAO as you must add/remove a letter.

Comment: Doh! Good point, thanks, I've reverted that bit. @PiIsNot3 has a much more efficient answer for that one anyway

Comment: Good Job! You can also go directly from TA to TAP and from SIP to TIPS

Answer (score 7):

KNIGHT to TIME using just 11 intermediate words.

> KNIGHT
>  think
>  knit
>  stink
>  nits
>  tin
>  it
>  i
>  si
>  its
>  stim - this may be questionable, but exists in a [modern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stimming) and an [older](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/stim) sense.
>  emits
>  TIME

Comment: If stim is too eclectic, you could always try the more common mist, I suppose.

Comment: @El-Guest That wouldn’t follow the rules of reversing the word and adding or removing a letter.

Comment: Could you do it -> tie -> emit -> time (or must you always add and remove a letter)? I feel it says "may"...

Answer (score 7):

Partial:

4. start:  SLEEPY
   end:    SLEEPER
   (suggested 16 intermediate words)

   > SLEEPY, PEELS, SEEP, PEE, WEEP, PEW, WE, EWE, EWES, SEE, EVES, SEVER, REVELS, LEVER, REEL, LEPER, REPELS, SLEEPER (16)

Comment: You can save two words by doing EWES -> SEE -> EELS -> LEE -> REEL, I believe

Comment: Nice! Take it and compile em all for the win!

Comment: Thanks! I was actually really close on this one but couldn’t figure out how to go from WE to REEL. I actually had EWE written down at one point, but I didn’t think that would go anywhere, so props to you for making the connection that I couldn’t! :)

Answer (score 4):

Solution for BLOG to ABOUT in 12

> BLOG 
>  GOB 
>  BONG 
>  NOB 
>  ON 
>  NOT 
>  TO 
>  BOT 
>  STOB 
>  BOUTS 
>  STUB 
>  BUT 
>  TUBA 
>  ABOUT