# Choo-choo! Word trains

Tags: word, wordplay, no-computers, graph-theory

All aboard the Word Train *Express*!

Engineering a word train is simple:  I'll give you the locomotive (the first word) and the caboose (the last word), and I'll specify the number of boxcars (intermediate words), and then you construct the train.

Like this:

```
Locomotive:  PORCHES
Number of boxcars:  4
Caboose:  STATIONARY


-------------------------------------------

Solution:

PORCHES
 ORCHESTRA
     ESTRANGE
      STRANGEST
           GESTATION
             STATIONARY
```

And like this:

```
Locomotive:  COLONIALIST
Number of boxcars:  5
Caboose:  INGENUITY


-------------------------------------------

Solution:

COLONIALIST
       LISTEN
         STENCH
           ENCHANT
             CHANTING
                 TINGE
                  INGENUITY
```

Note:
— Each unit must be indented from the previous unit by at least one letter
— Each unit must extend beyond the previous unit by at least one letter
— Each unit must overlap the previous unit by at least **four** letters
— Each unit must overlap the *previous previous* unit by at least one letter

As always, I design my puzzles in such a way that they can be solved using only well-known words, so if you find yourself conjuring up increasingly obscure words, you may be overthinking it.

See if you can construct the following four word trains:

```
The A Train
-----------
Locomotive:  GASLIT
Number of boxcars:  7
Caboose:  GINGER



The B-1 Train
-------------    
Locomotive:  SCRAM
Number of boxcars:  11
Caboose:  ESSENCE



The B-2 Train
-------------    
Locomotive:  SCRAM
Number of boxcars:  12
Caboose:  YESTERDAY



The C Train
-----------    
Locomotive:  CUBIST
Number of boxcars:  14
Caboose:  GINGER
```

---

**Epilogue:**

Nice work, @PiIsNot3 , @cpark , and @hexomino !  People really came up with some amazingly efficient paths from locomotive to caboose!

I realize now that by giving the number of boxcars, the puzzle became over-specified.  This didn't allow the puzzle solvers enough room to freely explore their own paths.  I'll keep this in mind in future puzzles.

In case you're interested in seeing the trains I had in mind, see below.

@WeatherVane — I would still be curious about the solutions your computer program came up with.

> The A Train:
>   GASLIT, SLITHER, THERE, HERETIC, RETICENT, CENTER, ENTERING, RINGING, GINGER
>
>
>   The B-1 Train:
>   SCRAM, CRAMP, RAMPANT, PANTHER, THEREFORE, REFOREST, RESTRICT, STRICTEST, TESTABLE, STABLES, BLESS, LESSEN, ESSENCE
>     —OR—
>   SCRAM, CRAMP, RAMPANT, PANTHER, THEREFORE, REFOREST, RESTRICT, STRICTEST, TESTABLE, TABLES, BLESS, LESSEN, ESSENCE
>     —OR—
>   SCRAM, CRAMP, RAMPANT, PANTHER, THEREFORE, REFOREST, RESTRAIN, STRAINED, INEDIBLE, EDIBLES, BLESS, LESSEN, ESSENCE
>     —OR—
>   SCRAM, CRAMP, RAMPANT, PANTHER, THEREFORE, REFOREST, RESTRAIN, TRAINED, INEDIBLE, EDIBLES, BLESS, LESSEN, ESSENCE
>
>
>   The B-2 Train:
>   SCRAM, CRAMP, RAMPANT, PANTHER, THEREFORE, REFOREST, RESTRICT, STRICTURE, TUREEN, REENLIST, ENLISTING, STINGRAY, GRAYEST, YESTERDAY
>
>
>   The C Train:
>   CUBIST, BISTRO, STROP, TROPE, ROPER, OPERATIONAL, RATIONALIST, LISTENS, TENSE, ENSEMBLE, EMBLEM, BLEMISH, MISHAP, SHAPING, PINGING, GINGER

Comment: This reminds me of [Bridge Words](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/23941/bridge-words-word-pairs-linked-by-the-front-and-back?rq=1)! :D

Comment: @user477343 — Cool!

Comment: Using rot13(pbzcbhaq jbeqf) is definitely a strategy... how many can we use?

Comment: I'm gonna have to work on this tomorrow. If someone else finds the solutions, I will just try to find another. I spent about an hour doing this brilliant puzzle, and I forgot about one of these rules, I think. Agh! How many solutions are therefor each train, do you know?

Comment: @user477343 — Regarding your questions:  (1) I try to use words which appear only as a single, unbroken word in a standard dictionary, without hyphens, apostrophes, spaces, etc.  (2) The solutions can have multiple variants.  Some are already known to me (e.g., the B-1 train has several) and some which are new to me will surely be presented in the answers.  However, all of the variants I have seen so far differ only by a 3-4 word streak.  I'm not yet seeing completely or substantially different paths.

Comment: Sorry, puzzlers.  — Correction:  Train C has 14 boxcars, not 13.  That was purely a typo on my part.

Comment: Hope it didn't derail anyone!

Comment: Hmm, was the "no-computers" tag there from the start? I solved all of them :(

Comment: @WeatherVane — Sorry, it was there from the start.  But if past experience is anything to go by, there is a possibility that no one solves this puzzle by hand, in which case I will re-create it for computers and you can be the first to post an answer!

Comment: I feel like I'm so close to both of the B trains and I hate it

Comment: Is it 14 and not 13? Great! I think that works out better for me, considering my mistake xD

Comment: Definition of SlowMagic: "provider of quality and creative wordplay puzzles, mostly stressing in the transformation of words." ~ Omega Krypton Dictionary. +1ed!

Comment: Thank you, thank you, @OmegaKrypton !  I do stress the transformation of words, but what gets *me* stressed is worrying about whether I have presented everything clearly, accurately, and unambiguously.  Puzzle solvers always manage to come up with something I didn't foresee!

Comment: @SlowMagic following your invitation I have posted a "computer" solution.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Partial**

The B-2 Train (10 boxcars)

> SCRAM
>    CRAMP
>       RAMPANT
>               PANTHER
>                      THEREIN
>                             REINSURE
>                                  INSURES
>                                      SUREST
>                                           RESTING
>                                                STINGRAY
>                                                        GRAYEST
>                                                                YESTERDAY

The C Train  (7 boxcars)

> CUBIST
>       BISTRO
>           STROLL
>                ROLLOVER
>                       LOVERS
>                         OVERSLEEP
>                                   SLEEPING
>                                            PINGING
>                                                  GINGER

Comment: These are using the wrong number of boxcars though ...?

Comment: I hope it's OK - the [last one](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/81015/superhero-words/81020#81020) I did, I managed to find significantly shorter solutions than the author intended, and they were accepted, so I assumed for this one it'd be the same

Comment: Clever and elegant solutions!  But now you've made me realize that I put myself into quandary.  I should have stated explicitly whether the number of boxcars was meant as a requirement or just a suggestion.  (And that also points out the difficulty with creating these types of word chain problems — everyone is working from a different definition of what qualifies as a word.  So I have to be pretty permissive.)

Answer (score 9):

**Partial**

The A-Train

> GASLIT 
>       SLITHER 
>             THERE 
>               HEREIN 
>                   REINVEST 
>                          INVESTOR 
>                                  STORING  
>                                          RINGING 
>                                                 GINGER

Answer (score 4):

Here's my answer for b1:

> SCRAM
>  
>     CRAMP
>        RAMPANT
>                PANTHER
>                       THEREFORE
>                              REFOREST
>                                        RESTART
>  
>                                             STARTLE
>  
>                                                  ARTLESS
>  
>                                                         LESSEN
>  
>                                                           ESSENCE

Answer (score 3):

I previously refrained from posting this computer solution because of the "no-computers" tag.

But now an answer has been accepted and @SlowMagic invited me to post. I found a lot of similar variants to the answers, but here are the **shortest** boxcar solutions I found:

GASLIT (<strike>7</strike> **5**) GINGER

> ```
> GASLIT
>   SLITHER
>      THEREFORE
>         REFOREST
>             RESTING
>               STINGING
>                   GINGER
> ```

SCRAM (<strike>11</strike> **9**) ESSENCE

> ```
> SCRAM
>  CRAMP
>   RAMPANT
>      PANTHER
>         THEREFORE
>            REFOREST
>                RESTART
>                  STARTLE
>                    ARTLESS
>                       LESSEN
>                        ESSENCE
> ```

SCRAM (<strike>12</strike> **7**) YESTERDAY

> ```
> SCRAM
>  CRAMP
>   RAMPART
>      PARTING
>         TINGES
>          INGESTING
>              STINGRAY
>                  GRAYEST
>                     YESTERDAY
> ```

CUBIST (<strike>14</strike> **6**) GINGER

> ```
> CUBIST
>   BISTABLE
>      TABLES
>        BLESS
>         LESSENS
>            SENSING
>               SINGING
>                  GINGER
> ```

I didn't find *any* solutions to the B-2 Train until I added REENLIST and GRAYEST to my dictionary. On the other hand, I didn't want to use a more exhaustive dictionary because it contains too many words I am not familiar with.

Comment: Excellent!  Thank you for sharing!  You must have written a very fine breadth-first search algorithm to come up with such highly efficient solutions.  BTW, I also made special consideration for REENLIST.  I seem to remember it being spelled with a hyphen... Or maybe that's just another example of the [Mandela effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/False_memory#Commonly_held_false_memories)...